# Find Polynomial coefficients

Tags: polynomials

How can I find the real coefficients a,b if the polynomial

$ P(X)=X^4-5X^3+8X^2+aX+b $ is divisible by $ Q(X)=(X-1)^2 $

So if 1 is a solution, I get a+b=-4; where should i look for other roots?

Comment: The root is double.

Comment: try: divide by x-1 first, and then divide the rest by x-1 again

Comment: Show that if Q divides P, then 1 is a root of P'(X).

Comment: @Yilun: you probably meant divide by $(x-1)^2$ first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just compute $Q(x)\cdot(x^2+cx+d)-P(x)=0$ and compare coefficients. This gives
immediately $a=-5$, $b=1$, $c=-3$ and $d=1$.

Answer (score 1):

If (x-1)^2 divides p(x) it is also root of p'(x) . Therefore 1 is a root of the functions differential by which u can find a then b

Answer (score 0):

Using synthetic division:

\begin{array}{rrrrrrr}
       & | &   1 &  -5 &   8 &   a     & b \\
     1 & | &   0 &   1 &  -4 &   4 &   a+4 \\
       & + & --- & --- & --- & --- & ----- \\
       &   &   1 &  -4 &   4 & a+4 & a+b+4 \\
\end{array}

So $a+b+4 = 0$.

Dividing again by $(x-1)$ :

\begin{array}{rcrrrr}
       & | &   1 &  -4 &   4 & a+4 \\
     1 & | &   0 &   1 &  -3 &   1 \\
       & + & --- & --- & --- & --- \\
       &   &   1 &  -3 &   1 & a+5 \\
\end{array}

So $a+5= 0$, hence $a = -5$ and $b=1$.